# Using NAudio to record fixed length wav, it crashes with "System.AccessViolationException" after the first file

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm using NAudio to record a fixed length audio file, but it crashes after the first file at the `TimerElapsed` method.

- I'm using a Timer that stops and starts a new recording after the `Interval` has elapsed.
- The filename is changed after each new recording.

This is the error I get.

```
System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

The class code is here :

```cs
namespace AudioService
{

    public class AudioRecorder
    {
        public string Location
        {
            get => location;
            set
            {
                location = value;
                Filename = $"{Location}/test001.wav";
            }
        }

        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public double Interval { get; set; } = 10000;

        public int DeviceNumber { get; set; } = 0;

        private WaveInEvent waveSource = null;
        private WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;

        public bool LoopRecord { get; set; } = true;
        public bool Recording { get; set; } = false;

        private System.Timers.Timer timer;
        private string location;

        public AudioRecorder()
        {
            Location = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile");
            Filename = $"{Location}/test001.wav";

            if (LoopRecord) setTimer();
        }



        private void setTimer()
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(Interval);

            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.AutoReset = true;

        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// ****************
            /// CRASHES HERE
            /// ****************
            waveSource?.StopRecording();

            Filename = GetNewFileName();
            StartRecording(Filename);
        }

        public void StartRecording()
        {
            if (timer != null)
                timer.Enabled = true;
            StartRecording(Filename);
        }

        public async void StartRecording(string filename)
        {
            if (waveSource == null)
            {
                waveSource = new WaveInEvent
                {
                    DeviceNumber = DeviceNumber,
                    WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1)
                };

                waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
                waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);
            }
            
            waveFile = await Task.Run(() => new WaveFileWriter(filename, waveSource.WaveFormat));

            waveSource.StartRecording();

            Recording = true;
        }

        private void waveSource_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveSource != null)
            {
                waveSource.Dispose();
                waveSource = null;
            }

            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Dispose();
                waveFile = null;
            }

            Recording = false;

        }

        private void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                waveFile.Flush();
            }
        }    

        public void StopRecording()
        {
            waveSource?.StopRecording();
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        public string GetNewFileName()
        {
            var tempLocation = $"{Location}/{DateTime.Now:yyMMdd}/";

            bool folderExists = Directory.Exists(tempLocation);
            if (!folderExists)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempLocation);

            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
            return $"{tempLocation}{date}.wav";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What's the purpose of the Timer? from the looks of it, it seems like you want it to delay a bit before it calls StartRecording?

Answer (score 0):

That exception basically means that you are crashing the 3rd party unmanaged code in NAudio, probably by trying to access an object that it is busy using or that it has already closed.

Your timer is going to fire every time your interval elapses, but you don't have any code to make sure that the previous recording is complete before starting a new one. In other words, StartRecording will get called over and over one the timer is started. If you want StartRecording to fire ONCE, then timer.AutoReset should be false.

A good way to troubleshoot these kind of issues is to replace all the calls to NAudio objects with console.writelines describing what is happening, and then run your program and observe the output.

Comment: Should I dispose the Timer and instanciate a new one when the recording is done?

Comment: No, the timer is not the problem. The timer is just a timer. You need to managed the lifetime of the NAudio object and make sure you're not trying to manipulated a item that's already closed. Your code is effectively multithreaded because of the Timer + async method, so you need to use standard multithreading principles to control access to your objects so that multiple threads don't try to access things at the same time. Replaced your StartRecording(filename) method with a console writeline or something and observe what's happening.

Comment: Except for the Timer, I have removed all async and multithreaded stuff. I still get the same error.
Can it be because it's a "detached" class used from a ViewModel?

Comment: No that doesn't seem likely either. The exception is telling that you're using NAudio wrong. I'm not an NAudio expert so I can't help much with that. Maybe NAudio is still busy when you try to stop the recording? I'm not seeing anything that makes sure the previous recording is finished before you start the next one. It's also possible that NAudio has rules about which thread is allowed to access which objects. The Timer's thread is not the main application thread.

Comment: What is weird is that the program was working well for about a year until yesterday. I think it might have something to do with an OS upgrade (win11). Thanks.

Comment: Oh that would be a useful bit on information. In that case it's most liikely that you need a new build of NAudio.